# Cannot download MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, upgrade, updates

The repository `cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819) Focal Release` does not have a release file.

```
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal and run the following command to edit the repository list:

bash

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Look for the line starting with cdrom: and comment it out by adding a # at the beginning of the line. It should look something like this:

bash

## deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Focal Fossa - Release amd64 (20210819)]/ focal main restricted

Save the changes and exit the text editor.

Update the package list:

After removing the CD-ROM repository, update the package list to refresh the repositories:

bash

sudo apt-get update

Remove unnecessary repository files:

It's possible that there are files related to the CD-ROM repository in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory. Check for any files related to the CD-ROM repository and remove them. For example:

bash

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cdrom-something.list

Optional: Configure Software & Updates GUI:

If you prefer a graphical interface, you can also use the "Software & Updates" application to manage your software sources. Open it, go to the "Other Software" tab, and uncheck the CD-ROM repository.
```